# Parameterized abstract class constructor

Tags: c#, constructor, abstract-class

I have a class like below

```
public abstract class ABC
{
    int _a;
    public ABC(int a)
    {
        _a = a;
    }
    public abstract void computeA();
};
```

Is it mandatory for the derived class to supply the parameters for the base/abstract class constructor? Is there any way to initialize the derived class without supplying the parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Yes, you have to supply an argument to the base class constructor.

Of course, the derived class *may* have a parameterless constructor - it can call the base class constructor any way it wants. For example:

```
public class Foo : ABC
{
    // Always pass 123 to the base class constructor
    public Foo() : base(123)
    {
    }
}
```

So you don't necessarily need to pass any information to the derived class constructor, but the derived class constructor *must* pass information to the base class constructor, if that only exposes a parameterized constructor.

(Note that in real code `Foo` would also have to override `computeA()`, but that's irrelevant to the constructor part of the question, so I left it out of the sample.)

Comment: Damn... Beat me too it... And 123 does seem to be a popular default value. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You can create a default constructor in a derived class that does not need parameters and the derived class will supply default values, but you cannot remove the requirement entirely. It is a manadatory condition of the base class to have some sort of value.

```
public MyDerivedClass : ABC
{
  public MyDerivedClass()
    : base(123) // hard wired default value for the base class
  {
    // Other things the constructor needs to do.
  }

  public override void computeA()
  {
    // Concrete definition for this method. 
  }
}
```

Comment: +1 for including the override - which someone else omitted ;-)

Comment: @Marijn: I omitted it on the grounds of it not being relevant to the constructor call, that's all :)

Comment: I figured ... for a short moment I considered placing a nitpicking comment below the post, but was too intimidated by the 300k+ reputation of the author.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: But seriously, given the question, I find that this _is_ a better answer. "it compiles" and doesn't give raise to another question.

Comment: @Marijn: Will edit my answer to add it - not the code, just an explanation.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: I would _never_ ask you to change your (pseudo-)code :-)

Comment: @Marijn: I hope you would, if it were wrong - which happens more often than people think :)

Answer (score 1):

Add a default constructor to the base class and call the other constructor providing an initial values for its parameters:

```
public abstract class ABC
{
    int _a;  
    public ABC(int a)  
    {    
         _a = a;   
    }

    public ABC() : this(0) {}    
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't that be `public ABC() : this(0) {}` instead?

Comment: Yes, it's incorrect. If you want to chain constructors then you need to use the `public ABC() : this(0) {}` syntax; you can't chain a call to a constructor from inside the body of another constructor.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't have much to do with the fact that the base class is abstract.

Because you've declared a public constructor that has 1 parameter, the compiler removes the basic empty constructor.

So, if you want to create an instance of that class, you have to pass a parameter.

When you derive from such a class, a parameter must be passed to the base class for it o construct.